# Input Split Result in Form Field using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to split a select field that has several variables and on the change of options to split the text in the select option and have it populate a separate form field.

This is what I have tried:

```
<form>
<select id="cdetail" name="cdetail">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1~2~3">1~2~3</option>
<option value="4~5~6">4~5~6</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="cdtlla">

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cdetail').on('change', function (e) {

 $('#cdtlla').val($('#cdetail').val(this.value.split('~')[1]));

   });
});

</script>
</form>
```

Supposedly, the result of

```
$('#cdetail').val(this.value.split('~')[1])
```

is supposed to flow into cdtlla, but all I get is

```
[object Object]
```

instead of (in this example) "2" - assuming I use the first option

Comment: You cannot assign value `2` to a select which has no such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
 
    $('#cdetail').on('change', function () {
  $('#cdtlla').val($('#cdetail option:selected').val().split('~')[1]);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id="cdetail" name="cdetail">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1~2~3">1~2~3</option>
<option value="4~5~6">4~5~6</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="cdtlla">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

`$('#cdtlla').val(this.value.split('~')[1]);`